# doing var=$( cat file.txt ) prints contents of directory when file contains special characters?

Tags: bash, nextcloud

I use a bash script tied to a keyboard shortcut to read a specific chunk of a markdown file, and send that to the api of a shared productivity system (nextcloud deck).

the problem seems to be that there are a bunch of special characters in the file, because it cuts off after a section of a url  with /Mting%20Notes&openfile in it

I tried testing this with `var=$(cat MUSTDO.txt)` and then `echo $var` in the gnome shell it prints out the contents of the entire directory.

How do I set the variable to the contents of the file, special characters and all, without breaking anything?

here is the full script i use:

```
#!/bin/bash
#pullout tasks section from local file
awk '/xstart/{flag=1; next} /xend/{flag=0} flag' /home/user1/NotesToSelf/1TASKS_PAD_ALWAYS_VIEW.md > MUSTDO.txt

#set as var, i think this is where things break?
MUSTDO=$(cat MUSTDO.txt)

#send $MUSTDO to nxclouddeck api
curl -X PUT -u username:password \
'https://cloud.example.com/nextcloud/index.php/apps/deck/api/v1.0/boards/11/stacks/12/cards/539' \
-d 'title=Today Tasks' \
-d 'type=plain' \
-d 'owner=username' \
-d "description=$MUSTDO" \
-H "OCS-APIRequest: true"
```

I am assuming things break when i set the variable, but I am pretty new to scripting so i really dont know. any resources, advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: as i mentioned in a comment, running the script above results in the card i am editing in nextcloud to only display half the content its supposed to. it breaks off after a url with the content: /Mting%20Notes&openfile.

Comment: Run cat -v MUSTDO.txt to display any possible control characters

Comment: @RamanSailopal running `cat -v MUSTDO.txt` prints out the exact same content as cat MUSTDO.txt. if I try doing `var=$(cat -v MUSTDO.txt)` and then `echo $var` it still prints out the contents of the local directory.
the file contains essentially every special character, including email addresses urls,percent signs, brackets, etc

Comment: Where do you do `echo $var` (Should be `echo "$var"`) in your script?

Comment: I dont. im just trying to test what the variable $MUSTDO looks like, and the fact that doing that prints out a bunch of files in the local directory makes me suspect that setting $MUSTDO is where my script breaks

Comment: Always quote your variables to prevent word splitting and filename expansion. You do it right in the code in your question.

Comment: Aside: Prefer `$(< filename)` over `$(cat filename)` in bash.

Comment: Hrm. then why does the script not work? if the contents of $MUSTDO dont contain any special characters everythign works fine. but when i run the script it only sends the contents up till a part of a url that says /Mting%20Notes (im assuming its the %?) and then leaves off the rest.

Comment: It's your responsibility to URL encode the data passed to `-d`. If you want `curl` to do it, see `--data-urlencode`

Comment: Im not sure what any of that means but it looks like replacing -d with --data-urlencode did the trick! thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

In cross-platform, lowest-common-denominator `sh` you use:

```
#!/bin/sh
value=`cat config.txt`
echo "$value"
```

In bash or zsh, to read a whole file into a variable without invoking cat:

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<config.txt)
echo "$value"
```